# Hash Table insertion linear probinig

Tags: java, hash-map

My code is working fine Could you please review how I can make it more accurate and efficient?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearProbing {

    public static void hash(String store[],int index,int num){
        if (store[index].equals(" ")) {
            store[index] = String.valueOf(num);
        } else {
            index++;
            if(index==10){
                index=0;
            }
            hash(store,index,num);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String store[] = new String[10];
        for (int a = 0; a < store.length; a++) {
            store[a] = " ";
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;
        int index;

        for (int a = 0; a < store.length; a++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Num: ");
            num = input.nextInt();
            index = num % 10;
            hash(store,index,num);
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < store.length; a++) {
            System.out.println("Index: "+a+ "Store: "+store[a]);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not have to initialize string array with `""`. By default array values will be initialized with `null`. So afterwards, you can check `if (store[index] == null)`.
2. You are already doing '%' operation in for loop, no need to check `if(index == 10)`
3. String array is not required at all as mentioned by @kraskevich. But if you do need, make it as a property of class LinearProbbing. So that you do not have to pass it within methods.
4. No actual implementation of Hash is involved. So better rename methods.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd recommend to move declare store `10` in a final variable with a meaningful name. It's not clear what it stands for right now. It's the number of buckets, isn't it? You can improve the readability by calling `NUMBER_OF_BUCKETS` or  `BUCKETS_COUNT`.
2. The hash table actually stores numbers. There's no need to convert them to strings. It works slower and makes no sense. The meaning of the `" "` constant is also unclear (Why not `null`? The `null` clearly stands for no value). But again, it doesn't matter if you fix it and start treating integers as integers. Converting everything to a `String` is a bad practice (unless the data is actually a string).
3. The name of the function `hash` is also meaningless. It doesn't compute any hash. The name doesn't reflect what it actually does. It should be something like `insert` or `add`. I'd also create a separate hash table class and move this there (and make it non-static). That would reflect its actual purpose: adding an element to the hash table.
4. Having a fixed size 10 for your hash table makes its next to useless in practice (what if you want to add more elements?).
5. The `hash` function can be iterative (you can just loop until you find a free cell). It would save a lot of stack space if you decide to make the table bigger in the future.

To sum up, I'd do the following:

- Get rid of "magic" constants.
- Treat integers as integers, not strings
- Move the hash table into a separate `HashTable` class